# Session loses variable stored after parent.location.reload() called in PHP

Tags: php, session

Below is the main code that goes to the session and constructor after it stores data in the session.

```
if(!$result->uid) {
            
            $this->member_model->scripts("Wrong ID or PWD.");
        } else {
            $userdata['uid'] = $result->uid;
            $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
            //header('location: /adminBase.php');
            echo "<script>";
            echo "parent.location.reload();";
            echo "</script>";
            exit();
            
        }
```

On the login part, it stores UID through **$this->session->set_userdata($userdata);**,
Here is the part where it stores

```
public function set_userdata($data, $value = NULL)
    {
        if (is_array($data))
        {
            foreach ($data as $key => &$value)
            {
                $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
            }
            
            return;
        }

        $_SESSION[$data] = $value;
    }
```

[image]

but when it goes to the constructor through

```
echo "<script>";
echo "parent.location.reload();";
echo "</script>";
```

it removes previous session that keeps UID.

```
if ($class instanceof SessionHandlerInterface)
        {
            if (is_php('5.4'))
            {
                session_set_save_handler($class, TRUE);
            }
            else
            {
                session_set_save_handler(
                    array($class, 'open'),
                    array($class, 'close'),
                    array($class, 'read'),
                    array($class, 'write'),
                    array($class, 'destroy'),
                    array($class, 'gc')
                );

                register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            log_message('error', "Session: Driver '".$this->_driver."' doesn't implement SessionHandlerInterface. Aborting.");
            return;
        }

        // Sanitize the cookie, because apparently PHP doesn't do that for userspace handlers
        if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
            && (
                ! is_string($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
                OR ! preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{40}$/', $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
            )
        )
        {
            unset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']]);
        }

        session_start();

        // Is session ID auto-regeneration configured? (ignoring ajax requests)
        if ((empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) OR strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest')
            && ($regenerate_time = config_item('sess_time_to_update')) > 0
        )
        {
            if ( ! isset($_SESSION['__ci_last_regenerate']))
            {
                $_SESSION['__ci_last_regenerate'] = time();
            }
            elseif ($_SESSION['__ci_last_regenerate'] < (time() - $regenerate_time))
            {
                $this->sess_regenerate((bool) config_item('sess_regenerate_destroy'));
            }
        }
        // Another work-around ... PHP doesn't seem to send the session cookie
        // unless it is being currently created or regenerated
        elseif (isset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']]) && $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']] === session_id())
        {
            setcookie(
                $this->_config['cookie_name'],
                session_id(),
                (empty($this->_config['cookie_lifetime']) ? 0 : time() + $this->_config['cookie_lifetime']),
                $this->_config['cookie_path'],
                $this->_config['cookie_domain'],
                $this->_config['cookie_secure'],
                TRUE
            );
        }

        $this->_ci_init_vars();

        log_message('info', "Session: Class initialized using '".$this->_driver."' driver.");
```

Above is the part of the **Session.php** file. I tried to add **session_start();** on every function in the else statement as well as set_userdata function as people gave a solution but it didn't work. Session.php gets called from the construct file as below and then it makes a new session, which doesn't have UID. How would I be able to keep UID from the login part..?

```
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
            
        $this->load->library('session'); --> this calls Session.php file
        $this->load->model('member_model');
        $this->load->model('setting_model');
        $this->load->helper('iny_common_helper');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        
        if($this->session->userdata('uid')) {
            $this->memberInfo = $this->member_model->get_member_infoByUid($this->session->userdata('uid'));
        }
        if($this->memberInfo->no) { 
            $this->member_model->memberInfo = $this->memberInfo;
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Do you call `session_start` anywhere?

Comment: I keep debugging it.. yea session_start gets called after it comes to the constructor by $this->load->library('session');

Answer (score 1):

I think you are under a slight confusion.
parent.location.reload() is a javascript construct that trigger the reload of the parent of the current window. In your case, it will trigger the reload of the login page, because you are not in an iframe embedded in a parent page, you are in a page, you have no parent.
You need to replace the code below with a redirect to the page that redirected to the login page (or the current home)

```
    echo "<script>";
    echo "parent.location.reload();";
    echo "</script>";
```

You can use php or javascript.

php:

```
header('Location: https://example.com/');
```

javascript:

```
echo "<script>";    
window.location.replace("https://example.com/");
echo "</script>";
```

I would use php :), in your case the else branch would become:

```
} else {
    $userdata['uid'] = $result->uid;
    $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
    header('Location: https://example.com/');
    exit;
}
```

Do not forget tu replace the example.com with your correct url.
The exit (or die()) statement is important, should be present, also the header() function only works if it is the first output (no echo's, print's, etc before), otherwise you will need to use the javascript redirect.

Comment: Unfortunately, it goes the same constructor with the way you instructed me.